# Get UserID on ascx - no code behind

Tags: dotnetnuke

I would like to get the userID of the current logged on user in DotNetNuke on a custom module. It's important not to use any functions from the code behind. Any ideas?

Comment: In my opinion, this code should work without an issue: <%= UserInfo != null ? UserInfo.UserID : -1 %>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your ASCX File inherits from PortalModuleBase (or a class that ultimately inherits from that) you can use something like

```
<%= UserId %>
```

That will spit it out on the page.

edit: updated to include the right code

Comment: I think the example didn't come through.

Comment: Sorry about that, editing to highlight the code properly

Comment: Thanks Chris. Also, is there anywhere I can find the available variables I can use like the UserID?

Comment: This URL shows the PortalModuleBase class which exposes those http://www.dotnetnukeru.com/dnndocs/api/html/T_DotNetNuke_Entities_Modules_PortalModuleBase.htm

Comment: @ChrisHammond I'm having an issue with using the above token in my ascx file. It is inheritng PortalModuleBase, but the UserId value and UserInfo.UserID and UserInfo.Username are all blank.

Comment: @JamesGray is your control loaded within another control? If so, that control will need to set the ModuleConfiguration on the loaded control

Comment: This control is it's own PortalModuleBase created as a Module in DNN 7.1.2 and placed onto a container from the skin file for the page. What I did as a work around is instead of having back end code files or all my modules, I have a single module that just has a couple hiddens, then I populate it with the code file, installed that to DNN and told it to show up on every page.